# sunos change multiple files name

Tags: bash, sh, sunos

How can I change multiple files name in Sunos. I want to delete '!'.

```
sca_RetrieveResource!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_RetrieveSimcardChangeStatus!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.1.jar
sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.2.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.1.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.2.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.3.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.4.jar
sca_ValidateCustomerEligibility!1.0.0.5.jar
sca_ValidateIntercomTariff!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_ValidatePackageSale!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_ValidateProduct!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_ValidateProduct!1.0.0.1.jar
sca_ValidateProduct!1.0.0.2.jar
sca_ValidateReload!1.0.0.0.jar
sca_X_HEALTH_CHECK!1.0.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has resolved (for f in *; do mv  "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed 's/!/_rev/g'); done)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing multiple times, and I can tell you: don't write a script, doing this automatically. The best thing to do, is to open this list of filenames in a column-based text editor (like Notepad++), and create a bunch of lines like this:

```
mv sca_RetrieveResource!1.0.0.0.jar            sca_RetrieveResource1.0.0.0.jar           
mv sca_RetrieveSimcardChangeStatus!1.0.0.0.jar sca_RetrieveSimcardChangeStatus1.0.0.0.jar
mv sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.0.jar              sca_RetrieveTGInfo1.0.0.0.jar
mv sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.1.jar              sca_RetrieveTGInfo1.0.0.1.jar
mv sca_RetrieveTGInfo!1.0.0.2.jar              sca_RetrieveTGInfo1.0.0.2.jar
```

It does not look very good, but you can check if everything is ok, you can intervene when something is going wrong, ..., but if you mess it up in a script, you'll have an enormous workaround to get everything correct again.